# BroadcastReceiver registered in AndroidManifest not working

Tags: java, android, xml

Current Behavior: 
The messages are being broadcast, but the receiver never gets them.  I know this because the print statement in the broadcaster is printed, but the print statement in the receiver is never printed.  What am I missing/doing incorrectly?

Here's the snippet where I tried (multiple ways) to broadcast a message, which is inside a class called `IMService` that extends `Service`:

```
//NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST is a String
Log.i( "MY_TAG", "broadcasting received friend request");

Intent i = new Intent( NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST, null, null, NotificationReceiver.class );

i.putExtra( USER_ID, user.username() );  
sendBroadcast(i);

i = new Intent( NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST );

i.putExtra( USER_ID, user.username() );  
sendBroadcast(i);

i = new Intent( this, NotificationReceiver.class );

i.putExtra( USER_ID, user.username() );  
sendBroadcast(i);
```

The broadcast receiver (which is a standalone class aka not an inner class):

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
         Log.i("MY_TAG", "friends broadcast receiver received a friend request message");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name="NotificationsReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action  android:name="IMService.NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.Login"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.Register"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HttpRequest"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signin" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Messaging"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_messaging" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".IMService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".FriendList"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friend_list" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.Home"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.Friends"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friends"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.FriendRequests"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friend_requests" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.PrivateChat"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_private_chat"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.RandomChat"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_random_chat" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.Groups"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_groups" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.GroupChat"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_group_chat"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="activities.UserProfile"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Messages"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_messages" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:
After reading Mike's comment, I tried the following 2 things (separately), but the receiver still does not receive the message:

```
<!-- no filter -->
<receiver android:name="NotificationReceiver" />
```

and:

```
<!-- with a filter, and I changed the value of NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST to 
    public static final String NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST = "new_friend_request"; -->

<receiver android:name="NotificationReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action  android:name="new_friend_request" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here is my project's hierarchy:

[image]

Last Edit:

For anyone curious about the exact warning when I used a capital letter for the package name, here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of the `NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST` String?

Comment: @MikeM.  The value is: `new friend request`

Comment: That action needs to match exactly what is specified in the `<action>` element in the manifest for an implicit Intent to match. Also, you have the Receiver's class name as `NotificationsReceiver` in the manifest, but the code has it as `NotificationReceiver` (no "s").

Comment: @MikeM. Are you kidding me...if that little typo was behind my hours of staring...I can't believe I missed that.  I'll try it right now and let you know if it works. I wasn't aware of the action tag though so that's good to know.

Comment: @MikeM. I updated my question with what I tried based on your comment, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: If none of those broadcast attempts worked, then I would guess that it can't find your Receiver class. Where in your folders is `NotificationReceiver`?

Comment: @MikeM. I added a picture of my project's hierarchy.

Comment: Change the Receiver's `name` to `".Notifications.NotificationReceiver"` in the manifest.

Comment: @MikeM. I thought for sure that would work, but it didn't.  I tried it both with and without the filter as well. And I've made sure there are no typos.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. The implicit Intent, at least, should be working. I can't think of anything your IDE wouldn't be warning you about. Make sure all your package names are correct, and all your imports are pointing to the correct classes. You might also try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: I just noticed that the screenshot you posted shows a bunch of warnings on the folders. What's your IDE say about those?

Comment: @MikeM. The warning talked about inner classes so I ignored it, but it also mentioned packages have to be lower case.  I renamed the "Notifications" package to "notifications" and `<receiver android:name="notifications.NotificationReceiver" />` worked.  Using the filter as I did in the edit worked as well.  Thank you very much.  Feel free to post an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: That's interesting. I wasn't sure about the capital in the package name, so I ran a test, and it worked for me. I guess it's good to know that that can cause problems. I'll get an answer together, but it might take me a minute. I'm on a mobile atm. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeM. I guess it's just different depending on what you're using to compile your project.  I added a screenshot of the warning when I used a capital letter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using implicit Intents - i.e., Intents not created for a specific class - the action you're filtering for on the BroadcastReceiver must exactly match that which you use to create the Intent. In this case, the `NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST` String specified in the code did not match the `<action>` element in the manifest.

Also, when a Receiver is incorrectly listed in the manifest, firing an implicit Intent meant for it will fail silently, as the system won't be able find it. In this case, an extra `s` in `NotificationReceiver` was one problem. Another was that the Receiver is located in a subdirectory of `/src`, and therefore in a different package. This was corrected by changing the name listed in the manifest to include the subdirectory in the package name.

Finally, it appears that capital letters in package names - and, therefore, project directory names - can cause problems, and should be avoided.